# textTitleAttributesForState is Null until set, does not encode?

Tags: ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

In the Following code I would expect the `titleTextAttributesForState:` to return the default text attributes after a `UISegmentedControl` is created,

```
    simpleButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"My Button"]];
    simpleButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    simpleButton.momentary = YES;
    simpleButton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - titleTextAttributesForState: %@", INTERFACENAME, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) , [simpleButton titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]);

    [simpleButton setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f], UITextAttributeFont, 

      nil] 
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - titleTextAttributesForState: %@", INTERFACENAME, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) , [simpleButton titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
```

Though as you can see form the NSLog output it is not.

```
2011-11-03 17:28:45.492 io[80933:11903] IoUISESimpleButton - createElement - titleTextAttributesForState: (null)
2011-11-03 17:28:49.368 io[80933:11903] IoUISESimpleButton - createElement -     titleTextAttributesForState: {
Font = "<UICFFont: 0x99c2040> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px";}
```

Am I missing something?  Also it does not encode the attributes.

I have in my `- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`

```
    [encoder encodeObject:simpleButton     forKey:@"simpleButton" ];
```

then in my `-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder`

```
    simpleButton = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"simpleButton"];
```

It does not save the `setTitleTextAttributes: forState:` that I've set. ( change font, size ands Color)

I end up having to add:

```
[encoder encodeObject:[simpleButton titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]     forKey:@"simpleButtonTitleTextAttributes" ];
```

and

```
    [simpleButton setTitleTextAttributes:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"simpleButtonTitleTextAttributes"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

for the Text attributes to save.

Thanks,